# SQLAlchemy: TypeError when attempting to execute a compiled statement with bindparam

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/errors.html#error-cd3x) for SQLAlchemy make it clear how to call a compiled SQLAlchemy statement:

> This error occurs when a statement makes use of bindparam() either implicitly or explicitly and does not provide a value when the statement is executed:
>
> `stmt = select(table.c.column).where(table.c.id == bindparam('my_param'))`
>
> `result = conn.execute(stmt)`
>
> Above, no value has been provided for the parameter “my_param”. The correct approach is to provide a value:
>
> `result = conn.execute(stmt, my_param=12)`

However, invariably, when I run code like the code quoted above, I get a `TypeError`. What am I doing wrong?

The code I'm running:

```
delete_old_ties = (
        delete(self.account_entitlement)
        .where(
            self.account_entitlement.c.accountid == bindparam("account_id")
        )
        .compile()
    )
# ...

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(delete_old_ties, account_id=1)
```

And here is the error again:

```
TypeError: execute() got an unexpected keyword argument
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error I encountered is twofold:

1. I imported `create_engine` from `sqlalchemy.future`, which has a [different signature](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/future.html?highlight=execute#sqlalchemy.future.Connection.execute) than the original `connection.execute` method.
2. psycopg2, which I am using, doesn't use the typical `:colon` syntax when binding
   parameters, instead [it uses the pyformat syntax](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html?highlight=pyformat#bound-parameter-styles). This means that if I don't specify
   the engine or connection in the `bind` argument of the [compile method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=compile#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ClauseElement.compile), sqlalchemy
   does the "default" thing and uses colons, when it should be using pyformat in its
   string.

Putting these two facts together, the above code in the question must transform to the following code in order to avoid this error:

```
delete_old_ties = (
        delete(self.account_entitlement)
        .where(
            self.account_entitlement.c.accountid == bindparam("account_id")
        )
        .compile(bind=engine)
    )
# ...

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(delete_old_ties, {"account_id": 1})
```